# ActiveRecord Grouping/Count Query Help Needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count, group-by

I am using Rails 3.

Suppose I have the following archetypical models:  Blog, Post, Comment, Category.  Blog has_many posts, Post has_many comments and belongs_to category.

I want to know how many posts are in each category but only counting those that have comments.

If I do the following:

```
blog.posts.group("category_id").count
```

--This gives me an OrderedHash which is close to what I need but of course the problem is the count values include posts that have no comments.

If I do:

```
blog.posts.group("category_id").joins("comments").count
```

--this gives me the number of comments that are in posts of that category (it does the same thing if I put the join before the grouping).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option which will help to keep your query simple and readable would be to set up a [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter_cache) in your post-comment association so you can just add `where("comments_count > 0")` in your find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think I will go with this option but I would still be curious to see if there is some combination of AR methods that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Giving 'having' a try. Just hacked this together quickly....

```
Post.select("posts.id, posts.category_id, count(comments.id)").join(:comments).group('posts.category_id').having('count(comments.id) > 0')
```

Which would translate to something like...

```
select posts.id, posts.category_id, count(comments.id) from posts join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id group by posts.category_id having count(comments.id) > 0
```

Might have to iterate on this a small bit...

Comment: (After changing "join" to "joins" to get it to compile)..this returns the Post id and Category id for one Post from each category.

Comment: Right - joins. Apologies. You'll need to add 'count(comments.id) as foo' - that'll be set foo into the post object returned and represent the number of comments in the category. Yes - example was framed around all posts - now scope it to your blog - blog.posts.